# Check if this domain is already open in the browser

Tags: javascript, web, session-cookies

I am setting a welcome message for my website that should be shown at the first time that users enter the website. So I display a specific element for some seconds when first page loads. The problem is each time that users go to homepage of the site would see the welcome message.
Is it a way that I check if this is the first time that user opens homepage? 
I have no server-side code and every thing I have is javascript

Comment: you can achieve what you want using cookies baked fresh in javascript

Comment: Create cookie... Read Cookie.. `If { /**/ } else { /**/ }` sound familiar or need some example'

Comment: [Use cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

Answer (score 2):

You can set a browser cookie when the site is visited for the first time. Read the cookie. If cookie is available it means site is already visited. If cookie is not there it means site is visited for the first time and you have to display your welcome message.

**javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
   var visit=GetCookie("COOKIE1");

    if (visit==null){ //show your custom element on first visit
        alert("Welcome new user"); 
    }
    var expire      = new Date();
    expire          = new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
    document.cookie = "COOKIE1=here; expires="+expire;
};
```

for further reference also see: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/legacy/beyond/javascript/cookiecountexplanation.html

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // check cookie
        var visited = $.cookie("visited")

        if (visited == null) { //first visit
            $('.custom_element').show(); //show your custom element on first visit
            alert("Welcome new user");      
            $.cookie('visited', 'yes');     
        }

        // set cookie
        $.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to WARN rezCash that your solution requires his site be paralysed by jQueery

Comment: thank you for pointing out. i have updated my answer to inform that it is jquery and also posted link to js version.

Comment: I also had to add this plugin to my project in order to use your solution: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie